# Find Lipidic Mediator receptors

Tags: single-cell, literature-search, interactions, lipid-bilayer

I want to study the ligand-receptor interaction and I am searching for lipidic ligands( mediators), I have found 16 so far. Does anyone know any database where I could find more lipidic ligands. I was searching on LIPID MAPS website but I couldn't know how to filter search for the lipidic ligands. Any recommendation is appreciated.